# I disabled login options, how do I reset my password?

Tags: password

So yesterday I changed password on ubuntu, but today I wanted to revert it so I entered user accounts and tried to change it, but sadly I could not. It told me password is not secure enough or something then i disabled log in options, but i want it back as it was

[image]

I cannot use `sudo` as I don't know what password to enter.

Now I can not change password at all

any way to make it as it was?

Answer (score 1):

You can still set a simple password by using the `passwd` command:

```
sudo passwd <username>
```

Comment: I do not know the password in terminal any more and it asks me to enter it, i thought i deleted it so i do not know

Comment: @Levan Boot into [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) and run the same command minus the sudo part.

Comment: I ran into this same problem but found that I could execute this above *without* using sudo and it worked for me on the latest Ubuntu (15.10).

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem before, but as i was running ubuntu off a usb i had made complete backups, i suggest you use windows to locate the syslinux folder and change syslinux.cfg to allow the boot menu, it explains:) and then press escape when booting ubuntu and seeing a purple screen

at this point i dont remember what to do but im sure the search box tells you, i remember seeing a forum on how to reset or change if you forget your password

Comment: I have no problem booting in the os i just press enter on the log in screen and it logs in no problem but in terminal i can not enter  because it asks me password and I have no idea what it might be
guess i gave to re-install